# Is pinch and zoom functionality not available in iPhone 5 iOS v 6.0.1?

Tags: ios, camera, iphone, video-capture

I been using iPhone for almost 2 weeks and i am unable to pinch and zoom in the video camera whereas I am able to use pinch and zoom in camera. Is this multitouch functionality disabled on iPhone 5 running version 6.0.1(10A525) of iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - that feature is not available on any of the devices I tested running iOS 6.0.1. In fact, I've never known pinch and zoom to work on any iOS device while the camera is in video mode.

The video camera appears to be fixed zoom on the following:

- iPhone 5
- iPhone 4
- iPad Mini
- iPad (3rd generation)

Have you found somewhere that this should work? (Or some OS where you can zoom) I have always corrected the crop and zoom of video on post production using iMovie so perhaps I've missed this as a feature in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pinch & zoom (or zooming at all, for that matter) is supported for video. I'm on an iPhone 4 with iOS 6.0.1 and I don't have that feature either.